# how can I determine the number of affected rows in a SQLite 2 query in PHP

Tags: php, sql

I'm writing an application in PHP 5. I want to delete some rows in a SQLite v2 database file. I'm doing something like this:

```
$sqliteConnection = new SQLiteDatabase('path/to/db');
$queryString = "DELETE FROM myTable WHERE status='not good'";
$result = $sqliteConnection->query($queryString);
```

how can I know how many rows were affected by this query? how many rows have I deleted?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The PHP function [`sqlite_changes()`](https://www.php.net/sqlite_changes) does this for you.

> Returns the numbers of rows that were changed by the most recent SQL statement executed against the `dbhandle` database handle.

Call it either in procedural-style:

```
echo 'Number of rows modified: ', sqlite_changes($sqliteConnection);
```

or in object-style:

```
echo 'Number of rows modified: ', $sqliteConnection->changes();
```

Comment: I'm voting you up instead of Owen simply because you did a more thorough job of explaining.

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend using [PDO](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) and [PDO:exec](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.exec.php), which returns the number of affected rows. (Or [rowCount](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.rowcount.php) if you use a prepared statement.)